# Attribute set using jquery not added to element only in IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Using jQuery, I add 2 attributes to an object element like this

```
$('#myObject').attr('codebase', pluginURL_IE);
$('#myObject').attr('onerror', 'InstallFailed();');
```

This code works on IE 7 and IE 8 but not in IE 9.

I inspected my tag using developer tools and found that the 'codebase' attribute is set and the 'onerror' attribute is not getting set in IE 9.

Any idea why I'm facing this problem only in IE 9? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `codebase` and `onerror` are not defined attributes and are custom attributes for elements. So, custom attributes are supported only from IE 9.

Comment: @Praveen: if both these attributes are not supported can you explain why the 'codebase' attribute works as expected in IE 9?

Comment: Take into account that the HTML browser from the Developer Tools is not dynamically updated like in Chrome or Firebug. I have added both attributes from code to an `<img/>` tag and then retrieved their values and it seems to be working, in the sense that the same values set are retrieved.

Comment: I said you it works from IE 9.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the .error() event handler in jQuery. The following is an example

```
$('#myObject').error(function(){
  InstallFailed();
});
```

Comment: not the exact answer I was looking for, but this could work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
$('div').attr({codebase: 'pluginURL_IE', onerror: 'InstallFailed();' });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/drxAj/)

Comment: thanks for the answer mate, but that doesn't seem to set the 'onerror' attribute either, but it does set the 'codebase' attribute just as my snippet did.

Comment: @awadm Checked the demo in IE9 - Both attributes are applied to DIV

Comment: I see. Can you think of any reasons why this attribute isn't getting set to my object tag?